# Firebase Dynamic Link with two android app versions (or flavors)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I have an app with two different versions (or flavors): Lite and Pro. They are basically the same, one with ads the other without (they were made before in-app purchases).

When creating a Dynamic Link I would like to send the user to app store only if he doesn't have any of the two versions, because both can handle the content.

But when you define the `AndroidParameters` you have to put the app package on the constructor, so there's no option to add more packages.

Is there any option to easily handle this case?

Comment: Looking for sth like that right now, did you find the solution?